# Como gerar imagens a partir de um vídeo?

Tags: php, imagem, vídeo

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de gerar imagens a partir de um vídeo, esse vídeo pode ser local ou do youtube.

Basicamente tenho um vídeo e gostaria que através de uma rotina "tirasse prints" do vídeo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa instalar o [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)

Após instalado use o código abaixo.

```
<?php
$frame = 10;
$movie = 'test.mp4';
$thumbnail = 'thumbnail.png';

$mov = new ffmpeg_movie($movie);
$frame = $mov->getFrame($frame);
if ($frame) {
    $gd_image = $frame->toGDImage();
    if ($gd_image) {
        imagepng($gd_image, $thumbnail);
        imagedestroy($gd_image);
        echo '<img src="'.$thumbnail.'">';
    }
}
?>
```

Siga esse [link](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10327812-How-to-install-ffmpeg-php-to-create-thumbnails-from-videos) para entender melhor o uso do ffmpeg